# How to use django template dot notation inside a for loop

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to retrieve the value of a dictionary key and display that on the page in a Django template:

```
{% for dictkey in keys %}
    <p> {{ mydict.dictkey }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

(let's say 'keys' and 'mydict' have been passed into the template in the Context)

Django renders the page but without the dictionary contents ("Invalid template variable")

I assume the problem is that it is trying to do mydict['dictkey'] instead of mydict[*actual key IN the variable dictkey*]? How does one "escape" this behavior?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**:
Based on the answers received, I need to add that I'm actually looking specifically for how to achieve a key lookup inside a for loop. This is more representative of my actual code:

```
{% for key, value in mydict1.items %}
    <p> {{ mydict2.key }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Basically, I have two dictionaries that share the same keys, so I can't do the items() trick for the second one.

Comment: The less fancy logic in the template the better. Try and prepare the data in an easily templatable fashion before passing it to be rendered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948/django-templates-and-variable-attributes/50425#50425) to a (possibly duplicate) related question.

It creates a custom filter that, when applied to a dictionary with a key as it's argument, does the lookup on the dictionary using the key and returns the result.

Code:

```
@register.filter
def lookup(d, key):
    if key not in d:
        return None
    return d[key]
```

Usage:

```
{% for dictkey in dict1.keys %}
    <p> {{ dict2|lookup:dictkey }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Registering the filter is covered in the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-custom-filters).

I find it sad that this sort of thing isn't built in.

Comment: @Cameron: nice, that looks like it'll do what I want! Thanks! But yea shouldn't have to use a custom filter like this for something so simple. At least I now know about custom filters :)

Comment: @mindthief: Glad to have helped. If the limitations intentionally imposed in Django templates start to get to you too much, you might want to consider switching to another templating language -- [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) is excellent and has similar syntax but many more features (including dictionary lookups!)

Comment: Thanks for the tips! So I'm having a little trouble getting the custom filter to work atm -- I put it in a file myextras.py which is located in the same folder as the django project. Added {% load myextras %} at the top of the template.html file, and the file contains the code you provided (@register filter def lookup...). I also added 'from django import template' and 'register = template.Library()' to this file to see if that would work, but I still get the error message "myextras is not a valid tag library: Template library myextras not found, tried django.templatetags.myextras". Any ideas?

Comment: @mindthief: Sounds like Django can't find myextras (your code seems correct). Is `myextras.py` in the `templatetags` directory? Is there an empty `__init__.py` file in the directory? Make sure your directory is set up exactly as per the [instructions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout)

Comment: @Cameron: Yes, that was it! Ugh, I was hesitant to add a new app just to get the filter to work, so I had tried to just put the templatetags/ folder in the main django project folder (didn't have any apps in this project). I figured that it should be able to find it in that folder just the same as if it were in an "installed app", but apparently not. I tried that now and it worked -- that is, I did 'python manage.py startapp extras'. And then copied templatetags/ into that folder, added 'myproj.extras' to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py, and that did it. Really appreciate the assistance! :)

Comment: You could have used `d.get(key)`

Answer (score 1):

From http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for

> This can also be useful if you need to access the items in a dictionary. For example, if your context contained a dictionary data, the following would display the keys and values of the dictionary:

```
{% for key, value in data.items %}
    {{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

The trick is that you need to call `dict.items()` to get the `(key, value)` pair.

Comment: I actually did do that, but for another dict. The problem I guess is that I actually have two dictionaries that share the same keys. One of them is in the for loop as:
for key, value in myDict1.items:
    <p> {{ myDict2.key }} </p>

Answer (score 1):

See the docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for

```
{% for key, value in data.items %}
    {{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```